# Subtract values from list of dictionaries from another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries.

```
foo = [{'Tom': 8.2}, {'Bob': 16.7}, {'Mike': 11.6}]
bar = [{'Tom': 4.2}, {'Bob': 6.7}, {'Mike': 10.2}]
```

The subtraction of a and b should be updated in foo:

```
foo = [{'Tom': 4.0}, {'Bob': 10.0}, {'Mike': 1.4}]
```

Now I tried this with two loops and the `zip`-function:

```
def sub(a,b):       
    for mydict,mydictcorr in zip(a,b):
        {k:[x-y for x, y in mydict[k], mydictcorr[k]] for k in mydict}
    return mydict
print sub(foo,bar)
```

I get a `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. Where's my mistake?

Comment: Your data structures are wrong.  `foo` and `bar` probably shouldn't be lists of dictionaries.  Or at least the dictionaries should not have different keys.  What are you representing?  What will you need to do with the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close. The issue was the list comprehension you had in your dictionary comprehension. `mydict[k], mydictcorr[k]` were both returning floats, but you were trying to iterate over them `[x-y for x, y in mydict[k], mydictcorr[k]]`.

This will work for you:

```
def sub(base, subtract):
    corrected = []
    for base_dict, sub_dict in zip(base, subtract):
        corrected.append({k: v - sub_dict.get(k, 0) for k, v in base_dict.items()})
    return corrected
```

Or as a much less readable one-liner (because I wanted to see if I could):

```
def sub(base, subtract):
    return [{k: v - sub_dict.get(k, 0) for k, v in base_dict.items()} for base_dict, sub_dict in zip(base, subtract)]
```

Having said that, you may still see some weird results when you subtract floats. Eg, `{'Tom': 3.999999999999999}`. You may want to wrap `v - sub_dict.get(k, 0)` in a call to round.

Comment: @GeoEki Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can build dictionaries from `foo` and `bar` and use list comprehension:

```
a = dict([next(x.iteritems()) for x in foo])    
b = dict([next(x.iteritems()) for x in bar])

sub_dict = dict([(key, round(a[key] - b.get(key, 0), 1)) for key in a])
```

Output:

```
{'Bob': 10.0, 'Mike': 1.4, 'Tom': 4.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dicts in `foo` updated you can do it directly as lists and dicts are both immutable:

```
def sub(a, b):
    for d1, d2 in zip(a, b):
        for k, v in d2.items():
            d1[k] -= v
```

Any changes will be reflected in your list which just holds references to your dicst:

```
In [2]: foo
Out[2]: [{'Tom': 8.2}, {'Bob': 16.7}, {'Mike': 11.6}]

In [3]: sub(foo, bar)

In [4]: foo
Out[4]: [{'Tom': 3.999999999999999}, {'Bob': 10.0}, {'Mike': 1.4000000000000004}]
```

As you can see you also need to be aware of [floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations)